# Unable to mount my WD My passport 1 TB in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, hard-drive, exfat

Whenever I connect the device I get the following error. Any idea what is wrong and how to correct it?

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/som/My Passport:
Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/som/My Passport"' exited with non-zero exit status 32:
mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

Comment: Is the hd formatted in ntfs cause it is being read as exfat. Have you tried to mount this in terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exfat file system is not installed by default.

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Reboot and plug had back in.

Comment: If this solved your question please mark it as best answer

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message: `mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'`. On your system, the file `/proc/filesystems` has a list of all the filesystem types your system supports (without extra effort). Or, read `man mount`. You probably want "`-t vfat`"